# Is thera a way to find forced execution context on datastore objects, somewhere in ODI metadata database?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a ODI 12c project with 30 mappings. I need to check if every "Component context" on every datastore object (source or target) is set to "Execution context" (not forced).
Is there a way to achive this by querying ODI underlying database so I don't have to do this manually, and to avoid possible mistakes ?

I have a list of ODI 12c Repository tables and comments on table columns which I got from the Oracle support website, and after hours of digging through database I still can't see this information stored in any table.

My package is located in SNP_PACKAGE, SNP_MAPPING has info about mapping , and SNP_MAP_COMP describes objects in mapping. 
I have searched through many different tables as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late but for anyone else looking

Messing about the tables is a no-no. APIs are better. Specially if you are to modify anything.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odija/index.html

Run the following groovy script in ODI (Tools/Groovy/New Script). Should be simple enough to modify. Using the SDK gets a lot easier if you manage to set up a complete development env in IntelliJ or another Java IDE. Groovy in ODI opens up a whole new world.

```
//Created by DI Studio
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.Mapping
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder

tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()

IMappingFinder mapf = (IMappingFinder) tme.getFinder(Mapping.class)
Collection<Mapping> mappings = mapf.findByProject("PROJECT","FOLDER")
println("Found ${mappings.size()} mappings")

mappings.each { map ->
    map.physicalDesigns.each{ phys ->
        phys.physicalNodes.each{ node ->
            println("${map.project.name}...${map.parentFolder.parentFolder?.name}.${map.parentFolder.name}.${map.name}.${phys.name}.${node.name}.defaultContext=${(node.context.defaultContext) ? "default" : node.context.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

It prints default or the set (forced) context. Seems forced context has been deprecated in 12c. Physical.node.context.defaultContext seems to mirror Component Context (Forced) in ODI Studio 12.2.1.3.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odija/index.html

**Update 2019-12-20 - including getExecutionContextName** 
The following script lists in a hierarchical manner and maybe easier to read the code. Not sure if you get what you are originally was after without having mapping with your exact setup.

```
//Created by DI Studio
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.Mapping
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.component.DatastoreComponent

tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()

String project = "PROJECT"
String parentFolder = "PARENT_FOLDER"

IMappingFinder mapf = (IMappingFinder) tme.getFinder(Mapping.class)
Collection<Mapping> mappings = mapf.findByProject(project, parentFolder)
println("Found ${mappings.size()} mappings")

println "Project: ${project}"
mappings.each { map ->
    println "\tMapping: ..${map.parentFolder.parentFolder?.name}/${map.parentFolder.name}/${map.name}"
    map.physicalDesigns.each{ phys ->
        println "\t\tPhysical: ${phys.name}"
        phys.physicalNodes.each{ node ->
            println "\t\t\tNode: ${node.name}"
            println "\t\t\t\tdefaultContext: ${(node.context.defaultContext)}" 
            println "\t\t\t\tNode context name: ${node.context.name}"
            println "\t\t\t\tDatastoreComponent ExecutionContextName: ${DatastoreComponent.getDatastoreComponent(node)?.getExecutionContextName(node).toString()}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that Component Context (Forced) is returned by this method
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odija/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/component/DatastoreComponent.html#getExecutionContextName-oracle.odi.domain.mapping.physical.MapPhysicalNode-

do you know how to print that? I dont know groovy or java.

Comment: @keciga, I updated the answer to include getExecutionContextName

Answer (score 0):

Below is a list of some tables and columns that might hold the value you are looking for.

[image: Table+Column list for finding execution context]

These tables and columns are from ODI 12.1.2, depending on the exact ODI version you are using, the structure could be a little different.

Comment: none of these. some of these tabes containt context information of already executed scenarios. What I need is current state of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a query to retrieve this information directly from database.

-- Forced Contexts on Datastores in Mapping

```
SELECT MAPP.NAME MAP_NAME, MAPP_COMP.NAME DATASTORE_NAME, 
MAPP_REF.QUALIFIED_NAME FORCE_CONTEXT
FROM SNP_MAPPING MAPP
   INNER JOIN SNP_MAP_REF MAPP_REF 
       ON MAPP_REF.I_OWNER_MAPPING = MAPP.I_MAPPING
    INNER JOIN SNP_MAP_PROP MAPP_PROP  
       ON MAPP_REF.I_MAP_REF = MAPP_PROP.I_PROP_XREF_VALUE
   INNER JOIN ODIW12.SNP_MAP_COMP MAPP_COMP 
       ON MAPP_COMP.I_MAP_COMP = MAPP_PROP.I_MAP_COMP
WHERE
   MAPP_REF.ADAPTER_INTF_TYPE = 'IContext' 
   and MAPP.NAME like %yourMapping%
```